# How to Pass params in g:link

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to pass two params via g:link like below

`<g:link controller="ClaimDetails" action="downloadFile1" params="[basePath:${session.basePath}, projCode:${session.projCode}]"><g:message code="claimDetails.ling.notice" /></g:link>`

but it gives me an error like

> Attribute value quote wasn't closed (controller="ClaimDetails" action="downloadFile1" params="[basePath:${session.basePath}, projCode:${session.projCode}]")

When i give params like basePath:'${session.basePath}'

It gives me the text only.

What i need to do?

Comment: as per below as mike pointed out really issue is here ${session.basePath} when you do `params="[]"` either now declare variables raw in there `params="[basePath:session.basePath]"` which should work same as `params="${[basePath:session.basePath]}"` only once around entire params map declared that `[]` is like you declaring `def a = [a:something,b:b]` in a controller which would be a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the ${} inside a g:link tag so:

```
<g:link controller="ClaimDetails" action="downloadFile1" params="[basePath: session.basePath, projCode: session.projCode]">
    <g:message code="claimDetails.ling.notice" />
</g:link>
```

Note: why do you use those parameters? cause you have the session object available on your action.

```
def action(){
    String basePath = session.basePath
    String projCode = session.projCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<g:link controller="ClaimDetails" action="downloadFile1" params="${[basePath: session.basePath, projCode: session.projCode]}"><g:message code="claimDetails.ling.notice" /></g:link>
```